# Reduce MySQL RAM usage

Tags: mysql, optimization, ram

I'm currently using the following configuration on my 16gb server for my ~15 websites (mainly WordPress and PHP Frameworks):

```
key_buffer_size                = 256M
max_allowed_packet             = 256M
thread_stack                   = 256K
thread_cache_size              = 256K
table_open_cache               = 10000
table_definition_cache         = 8192

innodb_file_per_table          = 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_flush_method            = O_DIRECT
innodb_buffer_pool_size        = 10G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances   = 10
innodb_log_file_size           = 1G
innodb_read_io_threads         = 8
innodb_write_io_threads        = 8
innodb_io_capacity             = 2000

tmp_table_size                 = 256M
max_heap_table_size            = 256M

sort_buffer_size               = 4M
read_buffer_size               = 256K
join_buffer_size               = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size           = 256K

query_cache_size               = 0
query_cache_type               = 0
query_cache_limit              = 128M

myisam-recover-options         = BACKUP
max_connections                = 500
```

Everything was going perfectly for a few month, I though I found the perfect balance between optimization and ram usage (some website are really SQL intenstive). But a few days ago I saw that MySQL got killed because the ram usage exceeded the available RAM (more than 10 GB on 16 if I remember).

So my question is, what are you supposed to reduce first on a MySQL configuration when that happend ? I hesitated between all the *_buffer_size and the inno_pool_size, so to free more RAM in less time I reduced theses variables to:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size        = 8G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances   = 8
```

For the moment everything is fine, I'm at 9gb/16gb, but I don't know if it's the way to go.

Thanks.

Edit:Added a sample query from a website

```
"SELECT c.cover, c.type, cl.slug, cl.label, GROUP_CONCAT(p.id) AS links
 FROM card c
 INNER JOIN card_language cl ON cl.card_id = c.id AND cl.language_id = " . $language->id . "
 INNER JOIN card_has_card_category chcc ON chcc.card_id = c.id
 INNER JOIN card_category_language ccl ON ccl.card_category_id = chcc.card_category_id AND ccl.language_id = " . $language->id . "
 LEFT JOIN card_has_links cp ON cp.card_id = c.id 
 LEFT JOIN link p ON p.id = cp.link_id
 WHERE c.type = '" . $type . "' 
 AND ccl.slug = '" . $slug . "'
 GROUP BY cl.slug
 ORDER BY c.id DESC
 LIMIT " . $limit . "
 OFFSET " . $offset .  "
 ;"
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it is best to use the defaults provided by MySQL.

I do see some settings that you probably increased to dangerous amounts.  Keep in mind that if MySQL uses so much RAM that it needs to swap, performance can fall off a cliff.

```
key_buffer_size                = 256M  --> 20M (Assuming no tables are MyISAM)
max_allowed_packet             = 256M  -- no more than 1% of RAM
thread_stack                   = 256K  -- remove (to get default)
thread_cache_size              = 256K  -- This is NOT bytes!!; change to 20
table_open_cache               = 10000 -- Do you really have thousands of tables?
table_definition_cache         = 8192  -- Do you really have thousands of tables?

innodb_file_per_table          = 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_flush_method            = O_DIRECT
innodb_buffer_pool_size        = 10G  -- the main tunable; 10G is good
innodb_buffer_pool_instances   = 10
innodb_log_file_size           = 1G
innodb_read_io_threads         = 8
innodb_write_io_threads        = 8
innodb_io_capacity             = 2000  -- Good, IF you have SSD, not HDD

tmp_table_size                 = 256M  -- no more than 1% of RAM
max_heap_table_size            = 256M  -- no more than 1% of RAM

sort_buffer_size               = 4M
read_buffer_size               = 256K
join_buffer_size               = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size           = 256K

query_cache_size               = 0
query_cache_type               = 0
query_cache_limit              = 128M

myisam-recover-options         = BACKUP
max_connections                = 500  -- see below
```

`SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Max_used_connections';` gives the 'highwater mark' toward `max_connections`.  You probably won't need `max_connections much bigger than the number "used".

For speeding up WP, hence the whole system,  O.Jones and I have made a WordPress plugin to improve certain `INDEXes`: https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed We detect all sorts of stuff like the presence of the Barrucuda version of the InnoDB storage engine, and other MySQL arcana, and do the right thing.

Comment: Hello ! Thanks for the reply. I installed your plugin on every WP and it seems that a few of them was still using MyISAM ! After that I updated some variables to:

```
key_buffer_size                    = 32M      
max_allowed_packet           = 160M     
table_open_cache               = 2048    
table_definition_cache         = 2048     

tmp_table_size                     = 160M     
max_heap_table_size          = 160M   

max_connections                = 200
```

And removed thread_stack & thread_cache_size. I think that it now should be better as some variable are divided.

Comment: @DK01 - Glad to hear that things are better.  Be aware that some variables should be set based on how much RAM is available; some based on other things.  Also, when switching from MyISAM to InnoDB, shrink key_buffer_size drastically and increase innodb_buffer_pool_size to about 70% of available RAM.

Comment: Hello, it's been a few days since the server run without any issues but I'm kind of afraid that the MySQL process keep eating more ram each days. I'm now at 45.7% of the ram being used by it, so i'm at 10.8G/15.6G. If it's stable then I guess that it's the perfect balance, otherwise if it keeps growing I'll have to reuce buffer_pool_size?

Comment: How much data do you have?  Probably less than 10GB.  That is, the buffer_pool is probably not a full size yet.  Hence it may continue to grow.

Comment: I have something like 16 databases but only 10 really used. One of the database is 830mb (pretty huge), and the total is approximativly 1,37gb. So I don't know if it's still "normal", but at this time my ram is at 11.7gb/15.6gb and mysql is using 52.4% of it

Comment: I don't think it's just because I have put a bit more mb in a few variables in comparaison with the one you gave, like I said in the first comment? The difference doesn't seems to be huge.

Comment: MySQL just got killed (OOM), so i'm putting the buffer_pool to 8gb instead of 10gb, same for the instances. Hope it will get better...

Comment: Consider setting up some swap space.  Swapping slows things down, but OOM kills them.  (Meanwhile, I don't have an explanation for the OOM.)

Comment: Yeah but I disabled swap for that reason, after that everything is slow and you have to clear it manually. So I prefer to optimize the MySQL configuration, it was running fine for month I never got a single OOM with a non-optimized config so it's weird. For the moment it's at 9/16gb so it's OK, i'll see in the next days.

Comment: Hi, I lowered the key_buffer_size to 20M instead of 32, table_open_cache to 1024 instead of 2048 ; innodb_buffer_pool_size to 8gb and... still get mysql killed 3 days later. I don't know what's wrong, I'll keep lowering theses values and tmp_table_size to see if it changes anything

Comment: Actually, I think I'll lower the read/join_buffer_size etc. variable as I have some website that aren't optimized. It will lower a little bit their performance but it might be a reason as well

Comment: Only in certain situations do read/join_buffer_size matter.  Perhaps other applications are consuming a lot of RAM?

Comment: No it's only MySQL that keeps growing. Since I reduced theses variable i'm "only" at 9gb/16gb, but it's in less than one day so I'll see if it get better at the end of the week. I have multiple websites that don't have good indexes, so I think theses variables can cunsume a lot on every mysql proccess

Comment: I need some more clues.  Maybe a query or two.

Comment: I added a query in my initial post. It's just a sample, I believe some are even more intensive because they get data from different tables (so a lot of inner join, group by, order by) etc. And it's for a website hosting a lot of pages automaticaly generated, so the database is probably a few hundred mb. And it's just for one website, there is 2 like that, and I host maybe 5 other (but little ones with cache - WordPress).

Comment: What's weird is that it was running fine for month even with all that load. I hope it has nothing to do with hardware as that host already burned one of my previous server.

Comment: Did you install that WP plugin I recommended?  It should help in 2 ways:  to speed up queries to decrease the amount of the buffer_pool needed for a given query -- thereby decreasing the thrashing that apparently is part of the problem.

Comment: Yes, on every WordPress on the server. But theses queries are from Laravel's websites (there is two). Yesterday I saw that they didn't had indexes on huge tables (6-10K rows), so for some query that are supposed to return only56 results, it took 20s instead of 0.007 now with indexes, so the CPU seems to be better now. I'll see on the long run if the RAM gets better as well as I had reduced buffer_pool

Comment: I'm glad it helped.  Sorry, but 10K rows is "small"; a billion rows is "huge".  Many Questions on this site are solved by adding, or improving, indexes.

Comment: Well it's what I did. The RAM is currently at 10/16gb, I'll see in the following days I hope it won't grow much more